# How to seperate two signals?

Tags: fft, filters, signal-analysis, noise-cancellation

I am new to DSP. My current project entails using DSP to analyse some datasets derived from experimental data. This data can be split into three:

- Signal A, which measures response from input X.
- Signal B, which measures response from input Y.
- Signal C, which measures response from input X + Y.

Signals A and C are essentially noisy sinusoids but B is turbulent noise (+ potential power line interference). The system is linear. I have attached examples of their FFT.

[image: Signal A Example]

[image: Signal B Example]

[image: Signal C Example]

Now my goal is to first analyse these separately which I have done using FFT. The second is to remove signal B from Signal C to determine if X is impacted by the presence of Y.

Now I have thought of potential methods to do this.

1. Use a low pass filter since the FFT for signal B indicates mainly high frequency noise.
2. Use statistical analysis to remove signal B from signal C (maybe pdf and some sort of simulation?)

I'm unsure of the suitability of these methods however, since the FFT of signal B shows some pretty constant amplitude noise at all frequencies. Is there any way of removing a superposed FFT from another? Any other suggestions to how I should approach this?

Comment: You haven't told us what the characteristics of signal A are, spectral or otherwise.  Please *edit your question* with the spectral content of A, and if you can, tell us about the system that generates it.  There _are_ things that you can do, but there are limits to how much you can remove random noise from a signal.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/76134/11256)

Comment: Apologies, I can't seem to edit the question I asked earlier that is why I posted again. I have edited this question and will flag the other one if possible.

Comment: It'd help to share the data (e.g. [ufile](https://ufile.io/), [drive](https://drive.google.com/), or [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have uploaded a sample of the data. The link is:https://ufile.io/f/vvpsh. Any help would be much appreciated.